# Pyramid Segmentation OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

I have a question about a segmentation method from OpenCV, namely [pyramid segmentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#pyrsegmentation) (found in `opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h`)

I don't know how to access the points from the segmented regions.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
cvPyrSegmentation(image, image_seg, storage, &comp, level, threshold1, threshold2);

for (unsigned int cur_seg = 0; cur_seg < total_segments; ++cur_seg) {
      CvConnectedComp* cc = (CvConnectedComp*) cvGetSeqElem(comp, cur_seg);
      // Missing part to access points from this segment 
}
```

I couldn't find much information on how to access the points from each `cc` element. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

P.S. For some reason the C++ version of pyramid segmentation is not supported in the later versions of OpenCV (>2.3), so a C implementation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Learning OpenCV* you are supposed to use the `CvRect rect` attribute of the connected component struct (`cc->rect`) which represents the bounding box of the component (otherwise `cc->area` gives the area of the component, `cc->value` the average color and `cc->contour` is not set for this kind of segmentation).

It also precises that it's up to you to use this bounding box the way you want, e.g. you may want to perform a [cvFloodFill](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut4.html) operation - so that to visualize the segmented component, using `rect` as a boolean mask to constraint the region that will be filled.